# Eight objects into distinct bins (number per bin and circular order matters)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

### Problem

I have eight objects {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} that I wish to place into some number of bins, such that:

- every bin has at least two objects
- all the objects are in a bin

Furthermore, within each bin, the order of the objects matters e.g. {a,b,c} and {a,c,b} are two different assignments. However, circular permutations are *not* distinct, e.g. {a,b,c} and {c,a,b} should be considered one assignment.

How many ways may this be done?

### My reasoning so far

First off I want to say I'm approaching this in a naive way with only a little knowledge of combinatorics.

There are 7 possible groups of bins (i.e. 4 bins of two, 1 bin of eight etc.): 
[2,2,2,2], [2,2,4], [2,3,3], [2,6], [4,4], [5,3], and [8] in this notation I just made up.

Starting from the largest bin in each group, there are $8 \choose k$ ways to select the objects to go inside the bin, where $k$ is the size of the bin.  There are additionally $(k-1)!$ ways to arrange the objects such that circular permutations are correctly treated.

This process is repeated for the remaining bins using ${{8- \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} k_{i}} \choose k_j} (k_j-1)!$, where $k_j$ is the size of the $j^{th}$ bin. All of the numbers are multiplied together to get the total number of assignments for each group. Symbolically,

$$ \prod_{m=1}^n  {{8- \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} k_{m,i}} \choose k_{m,j}} (k_{m,j} - 1)! $$

where $n$ is the number of bins in a particular group.

After doing the computations and summed across all the groups I came up with 20,888 different ways to solve the task. Have I done this correctly? I've started to second guess myself.

Thank you

Edit: Thinking about it some more I believe I also need to divide by the multiplicities in each group of bins.

Comment: Are the bins distinguishable?  If so, then [2,6] and [6,2] are different and you have undercounted.  If not, then e.g. [2,2,2,2] you would need to divide by $4!$ just to permute the bins themselves.

Comment: They are not distinguishable. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The bins are not distinguisable...  in that case, do you realize you are calculating the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of size $8$?  Your answer should be $14833$ according to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000166)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the commenter my solution is simply the number of [derangements of size 8](https://oeis.org/A000166), which is 14833. This corresponds with the result I obtained from applying my formula naively. Thanks, I learned something new from this problem.